# C++ Design: Template Function for Random Deletion by Index for list & vector

Tags: c++, list, vector, data-structures

coming from C. I'm struggling with how to design a generic function that accepts both a vector or list and then randomly deletes an element by it's index. (I'm comparing the runtime/performance of this for vector/lists.)

Here's what the code does:

```
1. Creates a vector of uniformly distinct randomized values i.e. { 5, 3, 1, 8, 10} 
2. Copies these values to a list and vector while maintaining sorted order


randCont = { 5, 3, 1, 8, 10}
cont2 = {} //list or vector
func random_insert( randCont, cont2 ) 
// Copy randomized elements from randCont to cont2 while maintaining sorted order
// prints container2 at each insert step
5
3 5
1 3 5
1 3 5 8
1 3 5 8 10

3. ** I need a function that accepts ideally vector or list and randomly deletes an element at a given index.

Output: Assume randomly selected indexes = [2 1 2 0 0] and input = {1 3 5 8 10}

1 3 5 8 10  //remove idx 2
1 3 8 10    //remove idx 1 ... 
1 8 10
1 8
8
```

I'm currently doing the deletion portion of this code with seperate functions for list and vector + and using repeated ugly code [SEE BELOW]. I'm also using std::next(), which isn't ideal because of possible compiler optimizations, to get element by index in the list. I do same for vector (unnecessarily) because I want to keep code similar for both container types. Is there a way to do this with a template/generic container function -- please explain?

```
void randomize_vec_delete(vector<int> &myVec)
{
    mt19937 generator(SEED);                            
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, distance(myVec.begin(), myVec.end()) - 1);
    int rd = dist(generator);
    vector<int>::iterator  it = myVec.begin();  

    while(!myVec.empty()) 
    {
        //myVec.erase(myVec.begin() + rd);
        it = std::next(myVec.begin(),rd);
        myVec.erase(it);
        print(myVec);
        uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, distance(myVec.begin(), myVec.end()) - 1);
        rd = dist(generator);
    }
}

void randomize_list_delete(list<int> &myList)
{
    mt19937 generator(SEED);                            
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, distance(myList.begin(), myList.end()) - 1);
    int rd = dist(generator);
    list<int>::iterator  it = myList.begin();   

    while(!myList.empty()) 
    {
        it = std::next(myList.begin(),rd);
        myList.erase(it);
        print(myList);
        uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, distance(myList.begin(), myList.end()) - 1);
        rd = dist(generator);

    }
}
```

Comment: @Ron The iterator is reset on every iteration `it = std::next(myVec.begin(),rd);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can very easily template this function.

```
template <typename Container>
void randomize_delete(Container &myVec)
{
    mt19937 generator(SEED);                            
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, distance(myVec.begin(), myVec.end()) - 1);
    int rd = dist(generator);
    typename Container::iterator  it = myVec.begin();  

    while(!myVec.empty()) 
    {
        //myVec.erase(myVec.begin() + rd);
        it = std::next(myVec.begin(),rd);
        myVec.erase(it);
        print(myVec);
        uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, distance(myVec.begin(), myVec.end()) - 1);
        rd = dist(generator);
    }
}
```

We simply change `std::vector/std::list` to a template parameter.

Is the code enough explanation?

Comment: Wow - I was close early just couldn't figure it - thx! FYI in your code there was a small bug which I fixed using the debugger. Do you know why we need to add "typename" before 'Container::iterator  it = myVec.begin(); '??? The compiler note is helpful but I don't fully get the logic of what 'typename' is doing. So the required line is 'typename Container::iterator  it = myVec.begin();' .... This was the compiler error:  dependent-name ‘Container:: iterator’ is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type:: note: say ‘typename Container:: :iterator’ if a type is meant

Comment: @colbythenoob You are right. That is called a [dependant name](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name). Iterator is a type that depends on Container. Name lookup and binding is handled different here then for a normal template parameter so we need to mark it with the typename keyword.